# Getting information about user interaction from application

Tags: android

I am working on an android application which can be used to capture the sequence of user interaction on device. 
This is to be done by an application, based on the users event a script  will be generated which can be used further to played back the records of events.
The application must have various button to start, pause, stop button for recording, script creation should also work according to button pressed.

There is a way to get this information from user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There is a way to get this information from user?

Generally, no, for obvious privacy and security reasons. Apps cannot spy on other apps' input, and apps cannot attack other apps by providing fake input.

You are welcome to:

- Collect this information about your own app (not other apps), though this will be rather difficult as the Android framework does not make it all that easy to collect this stuff, let alone play it back within your app
- Attempt to root your device and collect this application through very low-level means, though this will be even more difficult
- Make your own copy of Android that contains hooks for this and distribute it via your own ROM mod, which is yet more difficult